# Adding linked shaders from the Asset library with python

Tags: python, asset-browser

is there a way to assign shaders that are in a linked asset library? Iterating through the scene the asset lib shaders are not present - and as a linked asset, this scene link only seems to be created if I manually drag from the asset browser onto the geometry. Is there a way of doing this via code, so I can assign library shaders via Python?

[image: shady bizniss]